# select shows native colors instead of Bootstrap 4 colors in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, form-control

I want to use the Bootstrap css to style a "select" box in a form in a Ruby on Rails app.

On the Bootstrap site, they give this as an example:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Either if I use that example or a rails helper like one of these two:

```
<%= f.collection_select :language_id, Language.order(:name),:id,:name, include_blank: false, class: 'form form-group form-control' %>
<%= f.select :language_id, [['AM', 1], ['PM', 2]], {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

The result is the select being present but with operating system style instead of bootstrap styles.
All other controls show Bootstrap styles as seen in the following screenshot:
[image]

Instead of those black and green colours it should be the standard white and blue from Bootstrap.

This is what I have in my application.html.erb file:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You can check developer tools and inspect element, and see what exactly html is being created, than compare with others and do changes to resemble to colors.

Comment: Thank you@KamalPanhwar, that's definitely an option but first I want to identify if I am actually doing something wrong.

Comment: It is not really a solution since the problem is not only with the colours but with how they appear in general. It is not shown in the pictures but the whole box is ugly.

Comment: Yes I am not asking you make css changes, but what exactly html is created that will tell you where mistake is.

Comment: May be this because of different cdn you are using.. change the cdn according to your requirement.. :)

Comment: This doesn´t seem to have anything to do with my code or rails. I just realize that if I see someone else's example on the web the problem is there:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_select&stacked=h
If you open that page in Windows you will probably see the blue colors but if you open it with Linux you will see the system colors instead of Bootstrap colors.